# Microsoft Excel - how do I copy rows from one sheet to another sheet filtered by a value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Example:

I have Sheet1 that looked like these:

[image]

In Sheet2 I want an output like these (Here I want to get all rows with the Item 'CAMERA'):

[image]

I have a hard time composing formula to product Sheet2, can you help me what formula to use?

Comment: The pictures do not show use of filters.
Before using code, are you familiar on how to set one up (no code needed. Data-> Filter) ?

Comment: Yes I know how to use Data -> Filter. But the requirement is to use separate sheet for the "Camera".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This macro should do the trick:

Step 1: Do Alt+F11 to open the 'Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications'

Step 2: Hit F7 to open up a blank code sheet

Step 3: Copy the below coding onto the sheet:

```
Sub FilterandCopy()
Dim Equipment As String

Equipment = InputBox("Which piece of equipment?")

    With ActiveSheet.Range("A:D")
         .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="" & Equipment & ""
    End With

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = "" & Equipment & ""

End Sub
```

Step 4: Hit the red x to close the visual basic.

Step 5: In your spreadsheet, go to the developer tab, and click the 'Macros' button.

Step 6: Select the macro just created (called FilterandCopy) and click Run. (Note: A pop-up will come up asking for the equipment type, type in `CAMERA` to get the camera items)

Comment: Hi, I think macro is too much for me. Is it possible using a excel formula?

Comment: Not that I know of. I'll update my answer to instruct you on how to make the macro

Answer (score 0):

I like the solution you were given,
however here is another idea that might help you :
     * this assumes that you selected "by hand" from the filter a SINGLE value.

```
Public Sub CopySheet()
' Clear prev data
Sheet2.Rows.ClearContents
Sheet2.Rows.Delete

' Copy filterd data
Sheet1.Activate
Sheet1.UsedRange.Select
Selection.Copy

' Paste the filterd data
Sheet2.Activate
Sheet2.Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

' Copy the filtered "word" to sheet2, for example- "Camera"
Sheet1.Range("A2").Copy
Sheet2.Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

' Increase the size of the word above.
Sheet2.Range("A1").Font.Size = Sheet2.Range("A1").Font.Size + 5
End Sub
```